# Performing logical reasoning to find minimum function between two functions

Tags: mathematical-optimization, algorithm, logic

Consider the following two expressions:

```
f[x_,y_] := (1+x)
g[x_,y_] := (1+x*y^2)
```

`x,y` are bounded in a unit hypercube.  (Ignore the fact that `f[x,y]` does not have `y`-dependence, this is a toy example).
I want to find

```
expr=Min[f[x,y],g[x,y]]
```

Now in this case, `g[x,y]` will always give the minimum i.e. one can remove the minimum condition

```
expr=Min[f[x,y],g[x,y]] == g[x,y]
```

**Question: Is there any way to achieve this i.e. to know `g[x,y]` is always the minimum?**

What Mathematica can do, is find the range for `(x,y)` for which each of these functions are minimum or can also find the minimum value for each of these functions, eg. using `FindMinimum, FindMinValue`. The minimum value for these two functions is `1` but not necessarily for the same values of `(x,y)` eg. `g[x,y]` can give the minimum `1` even when `x!=0 & y=0`.  Also whenever `f[x,y]` gives minimum (for `x=0`), this automatically enforces `g[x,y]` to be minimum, leading to the deduction that `expr=g[x,y]`.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Don't understand " `x,y` are bounded in a unit hypercube". How to calculate `1+x`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In two lines.

```
FullSimplify[Min[1 + x, (1 + x*y^2)], 
Assumptions -> x >= 0 && x <= 1 && y >= 0 && y <= 1]
```

> `1 + x y^2`